# When does episode 9 of one punch man air?

Tags: one-punch-man

It's currently 9:31 am 6/03/19, and the website [yourcountdown.to](https://yourcountdown.to/one-punch-man-season-2) says one punch man season 2 episode 9 is out now. Yet every other website says something around one more day and 18 hours.

I cant seem to find it anywhere on the place i usually watch it. Is the country release date different for the US?

Answer (score 4):

According to

[LiveChart.Me](https://twitter.com/LiveChart_me/status/1135711695517564928) and [opm_anime](https://twitter.com/opm_anime/status/1135710483384655872)

> Today's broadcast of One Punch Man has been cancelled due to the French Open. Episode #21 will air next week on June 11t
>
> 「全仏OPテニス2019」編成により、本日予定していた「ワンパンマン」# 21「最強の悩み」放送配信は休止となりました。次回の放送予定は6/11（火）25:35～です。申し訳ございませんがご了承ください。錦織圭選手×ナダル選手を応援しましょう！ #onepunchman

Answer (score 3):

I've been following one punch man season 2 since it was released and **the usual time has always been on Wednesdays in the afternoon** US, NY(GMT-4). Firstly, the main website I use is the [Episode calendar for shows and anime in the US](https://episodecalendar.com/en/show/one-punch-man) and it shows the 5th of June.

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to find any american websites that have episode 9 till the 5th of June and if your lucky enough to find any, it would be RAW without any subtitles.

The release date for people in the US and english speaking countries is always a bit longer because of the time taken to sub the shows.

Comment: Just like pablo said, this weeks episode has been postponed till next week. Guess we gotta wait another week to see saitama vs bakuzan. Although we can all pretty much guess how it'll turn out lol.

Answer (score 0):

It was delayed by a week. 6/11/2019 and to the guy who said most American sites don't play till the 5th lol. It comes out soon as it's done airing

Comment: Welcome to A&M, do you have a source for the week delay? Besides that, as we do not condone piracy, I have removed the mentions towards illegal providers.